# Row-level access with inheritance in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a bit of a problem figuring out a good way to manage row-level permissions for an API i'm building.

Let's assume three tables:

- `List`
- `Notes`
- `Note comments`

`Notes` references the list it belongs to in a `list_id` column

`Note comments` references the note it belongs to in a `notes_id` column

I want to be able to load all the comments that a user has access to at once. If the user has access to a list i'd like the user to also have access to the notes referencing that list, as well ass the note comments referencing any of those notes.

Is there any specific good practice for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several... But i'd go for proven complete solutions like using and ORM of sorts... (doctrine2 comes to mind)

But you could just write your own with some simple joins ;)

Comment: I'm using phpactiverecord, which i'm pretty happy with. Is it possible that you could show me an example of a join query that would do what i need? :)

Comment: select * from list left join notes ON (notes.list_id = list.id) left join note_comments on (note_comments.notes_id = notes.id)